# Different span tags with different alignment in h1 tag Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need to nest 3 span tags (or similar) inside an h1 tag, aligning the first one on the left, the second one in the center and the third one on the right.

Can I do it via Bootstrap or does it need appropriate CSS?

Comment: Give us some code that you tried.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this

```
<h1 class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span>Left</span>
    <span>Center</span>
    <span>Right</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Bootstrap's [`justify content` utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="d-flex justify-content-around">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Bootstrap, but with CSS this is extremely simple:

```css
h1 { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }
```

```html
<h1><span>First</span><span>Second</span><span>Third</span></h1>
```